# Why should I use IHttpActionResult instead of HttpResponseMessage?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse

I have been developing with WebApi and have moved on to WebApi2 where Microsoft has introduced a new `IHttpActionResult` Interface that seems to recommended to be used over returning a `HttpResponseMessage`. I am confused on the advantages of this new Interface. It seems to mainly just provide a **SLIGHTLY** easier way to create a `HttpResponseMessage`.

I would make the argument that this is "abstraction for the sake of abstraction". Am I missing something? What is the real world advantages I get from using this new Interface besides maybe saving a line of code?

**Old way** (WebApi):

```
public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id)
{
    var status = _Repository.DeleteCustomer(id);
    if (status)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
}
```

**New Way** (WebApi2):

```
public IHttpActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    var status = _Repository.DeleteCustomer(id);
    if (status)
    {
        //return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return Ok();
    }
    else
    {
        //throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        return NotFound();
    }
}
```

Comment: I just found something interesting. I am not sure if these results can be verified by someone else. But performance improved a lot with some calls I did: * With an example using `HttpResponseMessage` I got the response back in **9545 ms**.
* Using the `IHttpActionResult` I got the same response back in **294 ms**.

Comment: @chrislesage 9545 ms is almost 10 seconds.  Even 294ms is kind of slow.  If you have anything taking more than 100ms then something else is at work there.  There's more to that story than meets the ete.

Answer (score 336, accepted):

You might decide not to use `IHttpActionResult` because your existing code builds a `HttpResponseMessage` that doesn't fit one of the canned responses.  You can however adapt `HttpResponseMessage` to `IHttpActionResult` using the canned response of `ResponseMessage`.  It took me a while to figure this out, so I wanted to post it showing that you don't necesarily have to choose one or the other:

```
public IHttpActionResult SomeAction()
{
   IHttpActionResult response;
   //we want a 303 with the ability to set location
   HttpResponseMessage responseMsg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.RedirectMethod);
   responseMsg.Headers.Location = new Uri("http://customLocation.blah");
   response = ResponseMessage(responseMsg);
   return response;
}
```

Note, `ResponseMessage` is a method of the base class `ApiController` that your controller should inherit from.

Comment: Took me a while to find out that ResponseMessage is now ResponseMessageResult. Perhaps it has been renamed recently? P.S. You have also missed a new keyword in the answer and thanks a lot for suggestion :)

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik `ResponseMessage` and `ResponseMessageResult` are two different things.  `ResponseMessage()` is a *method* of `ApiController` which your controller should inherit from, and therefore is just a method call.  So no `new` keyword is needed there.  You probably aren't inheriting from `ApiController` or you are inside a static method.  `ResponseMessageResult` is the return type of `ResponseMessage()`.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik I could have written `response = base.ResponseMessage(responseMsg)` to make it more clear that it is a method of the base class ApiController

Comment: Thanks, I had a service indeed that did not inherit from ApiController, that's why it took some time to find.

Comment: @AaronLS is correct. It should be `return new ResponseMessageResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.RedirectMethod));`

Answer (score 88):

You can still use `HttpResponseMessage`. That capability will not go away. I felt the same way as you and argued extensively with the team that there was no need for an additional abstraction. There were a few arguments thrown around to try and justify its existence but nothing that convinced me that it was worthwhile.

That is, until I saw [this](https://gist.github.com/bradwilson/8586562) sample from *Brad Wilson*.  If you construct `IHttpActionResult` classes in a way that can be chained, you gain the ability to create a **"action-level"** response pipeline for generating the `HttpResponseMessage`.  Under the covers, this is how `ActionFilters` are implemented however, the ordering of those `ActionFilters` is not obvious when reading the action method which is one reason I'm not a fan of action filters.

However, by creating an `IHttpActionResult` that can be explicitly chained in your action method you can compose all kinds of different behaviour to generate your response.

Answer (score 75):

Here are several benefits of `IHttpActionResult` over `HttpResponseMessage` mentioned in [Microsoft ASP.Net Documentation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results):

> - Simplifies unit testing your controllers.
> - Moves common logic for creating HTTP responses into separate classes.
> - Makes the intent of the controller action clearer, by hiding the low-level details of constructing the response.

But here are some other advantages of using `IHttpActionResult` worth mentioning:

- **Respecting single responsibility principle**: cause action methods to have the responsibility of serving the HTTP requests and does not involve them in creating the HTTP response messages.
- **Useful implementations** already defined in the System.Web.Http.Results namely: `Ok` `NotFound` `Exception` `Unauthorized` `BadRequest` `Conflict` `Redirect` `InvalidModelState` ([link to full list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.results.aspx))
- Uses **Async and Await** by default.
- **Easy to create own ActionResult** just by implementing `ExecuteAsync` method.
- you can use `ResponseMessageResult ResponseMessage(HttpResponseMessage response)` to **convert HttpResponseMessage to IHttpActionResult**.

Answer (score 35):

```
// this will return HttpResponseMessage as IHttpActionResult
return ResponseMessage(httpResponseMessage);
```

Answer (score 20):

This is just my personal opinion and folks from web API team can probably articulate it better but here is my 2c.

First of all, I think it is not a question of one over another. You can use them both depending on what you want to do in your action method but in order to understand the real power of `IHttpActionResult`, you will probably need to step outside those convenient helper methods of `ApiController` such as `Ok`, `NotFound`, etc.

Basically, I think a class implementing `IHttpActionResult` as a factory of `HttpResponseMessage`. With that mind set, it now becomes an object that need to be returned and a factory that produces it. In general programming sense, you can create the object yourself in certain cases and in certain cases, you need a factory to do that. Same here.

If you want to return a response which needs to be constructed through a complex logic, say lots of response headers, etc, you can abstract all those logic into an action result class implementing `IHttpActionResult` and use it in multiple action methods to return response.

Another advantage of using `IHttpActionResult` as return type is that it makes ASP.NET Web API action method similar to MVC. You can return any action result without getting caught in media formatters.

Of course,  as noted by Darrel, you can chain action results and create a powerful micro-pipeline similar to message handlers themselves in the API pipeline. This you will need depending on the complexity of your action method.

Long story short - it is not `IHttpActionResult` versus `HttpResponseMessage`. Basically, it is how you want to create the response. Do it yourself or through a factory.

Comment: The problem I had with the factory justfication is that I can easily create static methods like `ResponseFactory.CreateOkResponse()` that return HttpResponseMessage, and I didn't have to deal with the async stuff when creating the response.  One team member did mention the fact that the async can be useful if you need to do I/O in order to generate header values.  Not sure how often that happens though.

Comment: I think it is same as saying why do we need factory method pattern. Why not just use static methods to create objects. Sure, it is doable - every object creation does not merit a proper factory pattern. But then IMHO it depends on how you want to model your classes. Do you want to have logic to create different types of responses all crammed into a class in the form of multiple static methods or have different classes based on an interface. Again, there is no good or bad. It all depends. Anyways, my point is that it is not one over another and I personally like factory thing better :)

Answer (score 8):

The Web API basically return 4 type of object: `void`, `HttpResponseMessage`, `IHttpActionResult`, and other strong types. The first version of the Web API returns `HttpResponseMessage` which is pretty straight forward HTTP response message.

The `IHttpActionResult` was introduced by WebAPI 2 which is a kind of wrap of `HttpResponseMessage`. It contains the `ExecuteAsync()` method to create an `HttpResponseMessage`. It simplifies unit testing of your controller.

Other return type are kind of strong typed classes serialized by the Web API using a media formatter into the response body. The drawback was you cannot directly return an error code such as a 404. All you can do is throwing an `HttpResponseException` error.

Answer (score 4):

We have the  following benefits of using `IHttpActionResult` over  `HttpResponseMessage`:

1. By using the `IHttpActionResult` we are only concentrating on the data to be send not on the status code. So here the code will be cleaner and very easy to maintain.
2. Unit testing of the implemented controller method will be easier.
3. Uses `async` and `await` by default.

Answer (score 3):

I'd rather implement TaskExecuteAsync interface function for IHttpActionResult. Something like:

```
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = _request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, _respContent);

        switch ((Int32)_respContent.Code)
        { 
            case 1:
            case 6:
            case 7:
                response = _request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, _respContent);
                break;
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
                response = _request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, _respContent);
                break;
        } 

        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
```

, where _request is the HttpRequest and _respContent is the payload.