# Return json representations of data from WebAPI without strongly-typed IEnumerable

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

Having read a ton of different solutions and trying out different approaches ([here](http://codepedia.info/convert-datatable-to-json-in-asp-net-c-sharp/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398019/how-to-convert-datatable-to-json-in-c-sharp), [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/9bff34/3-ways-to-convert-datatable-to-json-string-in-asp-net-c-sharp/), [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDataSet.htm), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25408046/return-jsonresult-from-web-api-without-its-properties)), I am getting different (and unexpected) results from an API controller.

I need to return a datatable expressed as JSON, via a web api controller:

```
[IdentityBasicAuthentication]
[Authorize]
[RequireHttps]
[Route("Reports/Report1")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    DataTable dt = MyDAL.GetDataTable();
    if(someValidationFailed){
        Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Friendly error here");
    }
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt));
}
```

In Fiddler, the output appears to be encoded into an escaped string:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

"[{\"Site\":\"Headquarters\",\"Department\":\"HR\",\"FirstName\":\"Bob\",\"MiddleName\":null,\"Surname\":\"Fern\",\"EmployeeNumber\":\"444\"},
{\"Site\":\"Headquarters\",\"Department\":\"HR\",\"FirstName\":\"Alice\",\"MiddleName\":null,\"Surname\":\"Smith\",\"EmployeeNumber\":\"769\"}]"
```

However, the goal is to output plain Json (or XML if the client requests it):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

[{"Site":"Headquarters","Department":"HR","FirstName":"Bob","MiddleName":null,"Surname":"Fern","EmployeeNumber":"444"},
{"Site":"Headquarters","Department":"HR","FirstName":"Alice","MiddleName":null,"Surname":"Smith","EmployeeNumber":"769"}]
```

Is there any way to do this without creating an `IEnumerable<Person>` object?  The reason is that this class is specific to this one method.  I also don't want to use a StringBuilder, because the DataTable may be extremely large and I've seen memory exceptions thrown previously.

I'm new to WebAPI, so the answer may be really simple, but a code sample I can ask further questions on would be very helpful.

Comment: Web API handles serialization for you, so you do not need to call `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`.  That is why you are getting an escaped string as your return value.

Comment: Okay, so what is the approach to get the DataTable in Json/Xml format please?  I'm very new to this so easily confused.

Comment: Just pass the datatable to `CreateResponse`.  Web API will turn it into JSON or XML for you depending on what was sent in the Accept header of the request.  `return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, dt);`

Comment: OMG I don't believe it - you're correct, it does.  I had read elsewhere that returning the DataTable includes .Net framework-specific data.  Two days reading up on different "solutions", I didn't need to even bother.  Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Web API handles serialization for you, so you do not need to call `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`. That is why you are getting an escaped string as your output value.  Just pass the datatable directly to `CreateResponse`. Web API will turn it into JSON or XML for you depending on what was sent in the `Accept` header of the request. (It uses Json.Net under the covers.)

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, dt);
```

Comment: I had read that doing this also includes lots of .Net framework data (e.g. keys, relationships, etc), which is why I read elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Use anonymous type. JSON support serialization of anonymous types.

```
var persons = datatable.AsEnumerable()
                       .Select(datarow => new 
                       { 
                           Site = datarow.Field<string>("Site")
                       });

return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,
                              Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(persons));
```

Comment: I (perhaps incorrectly) changed `datatable` to `dt` to match my variable name, but then VS says, *datarow does not exist in the current context*

Comment: That's lambda expression -it must be `datarow => new ...`

Comment: Thanks.  The next error is on the `return` line, *Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult<System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<<anonymous type: string Site>>>' to 'string'*  I tried to create `return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, persons)` but that didn't work either

Comment: Use your code - change only serializing object to `persons`. Sorry I was used another method by mistake.