# Why should I use the HttpRequestMessage in my web controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

When it comes time to test my web controllers, I have found that mocking the HttpRequestMessage object can be a pain. It's quite a cumbersome object to have to mock. I'm also not a fan of the statefulness the Request object carries into my functions.

For these reasons, I have started "ignoring" the request object and have begun using things like:

- Implementing ParameterBindingAttributes to get specific access to the Headers I want
- Manually creating and returning an HttpResponseMessage instead of calling `this.Response.CreateResponse(...)`

I have found that this makes both my code easier to read and easier to test.

That said, before I go further with this approach, I wanted to make sure there were not any explicit reasons why I shouldn't write my code like this.

1. Is there any specific information that would be difficult to access unless I use the HttpRequestMessage intance?
2. Is there any thing info that my manually created HttpResponseMessage will be missing because it wasn't created using the instance method `CreateResponse`?
3. Is there any reason this might comeback to bite me in the future?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758615/why-should-i-use-ihttpactionresult-instead-of-httpresponsemessage)?

Comment: Yes, I haven't seen anyone use IHttpActionResult in away that doesn't use the `ApiController`'s `Request` instance. I want to know why people feel it's necessary to use that `Request` object. Especially when you can just do this: `return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Ok);`