# return type in webAPI call

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

What is the significance of using `IHttpActionResult` as a return type in ASP.NET WebAPI method call.
As this is a interface how can we return a result in the form of interface ?

 can someone explain the concept behind this?

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: There is a good expilanation here ; 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758615/why-should-i-use-ihttpactionresult-instead-of-httpresponsemessage 

Look for Behzad Bahmanyar's post

Comment: It's just an update to the previous standard of using `HttpResponseMessage`, though there's also nothing stopping you from still just returning an object itself.  Types like `HttpResponseMessage` and `IHttpActionResult` simply give you some more control over the HTTP wrapper to the response, instead of just returning the data vs. throwing an exception.  I guess it's not really clear to me specifically what you're asking.

Comment: ***Your question is basically [Why are interfaces useful?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/108240/why-are-interfaces-useful).***

Comment: This link explain some different return types for 
Web API controller. https://alastaircrabtree.com/choose-the-right-return-type-for-webapi-controllers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [Microsoft ASP.NET](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results) Documentation,

The `IHttpActionResult` interface was introducted in Web API 2. Essentially, it defines an HttpResponseMessage factory. Here are some advantages of using the IHttpActionResult interface:

- Simplifies unit testing your controllers.
- Moves common logic for creating HTTP responses into separate classes.
- Makes the intent of the controller action clearer, by hiding the
  low-level details of constructing the response.

IHttpActionResult contains a single method, ExecuteAsync, which asynchronously creates an HttpResponseMessage instance.

```
public interface IHttpActionResult
{
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

If a controller action returns an IHttpActionResult, Web API calls the ExecuteAsync method to create an HttpResponseMessage. Then it converts the HttpResponseMessage into an HTTP response message.

Here is a simple implementaton of IHttpActionResult that creates a plain text response:

```
public class TextResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    string _value;
    HttpRequestMessage _request;

    public TextResult(string value, HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        _value = value;
        _request = request;
    }
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent(_value),
            RequestMessage = _request
        };
        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}
```

Another Sample in Controller:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return new TextResult("hello", Request);
    }
}
```

And Its `Respond`:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Content-Length: 5 Content-Type: text/plain;
> charset=utf-8 Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0 Date: Mon, 27 Jan 2014
> 08:53:35 GMT
>
> hello

I hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. it was helpful. one more doubt i had. how the return type is interface. I mean i can understand returning an string,object of any class but how can one return interface?

Comment: @AmeyDeshpande you return a type based on this interface's rules, an interface contains rules and based on these rules you can return a type. in simple english :)

Comment: Sorry :(  can you please elaborate more? Not getting what you want to say.