# Converting Json Post Back Data To XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, knockout.js

This is my first web app project. I am using VS community, asp.net, bootstrap 4,  C# and JS knockout for my view model, the server side data is coming from the company ERP SQL database using Entity Framework.

The idea is that the user receives a list of items to approve from the Company ERP system, which are loaded into the View Model. The View Model is structured as a JS Knockout observable array and that each item is a JS knockout item of observables (see full code below)

Once the user has processed the items as desired, I want the web app to post back the whole View Modal as a Json object and for the server Post Controller to take this Json object convert it to xml to send into a SQL stored procedure for insertion into the SQL database, from the SQL database the data will be handled and inserted into the ERP database

When I try to action the Post I get a 405 "Method Not Allowed"

```
> "tags": {
    "ai.cloud.roleInstance": "[MYCOMPUTER].local",
    "ai.operation.id": "c07680cd8c845240a9e3791018c39521",
    "ai.operation.name": "POST ReqsTests",
    "ai.location.ip": "::1",
    "ai.internal.sdkVersion": "web:2.8.0-241",
    "ai.internal.nodeName": "[MYCOMPUTER].local"
  },
  "data": {
    "baseType": "RequestData",
    "baseData": {
      "ver": 2,
      "id": "|c07680cd8c845240a9e3791018c39521.66f8d951_",
      "name": "POST ReqsTests",
      "duration": "00:00:00.0279394",
      "success": false,
      "responseCode": "405",
      "url": "http://localhost:64234/api/ReqsTests/",
      "properties": {
        "DeveloperMode": "true",
        "_MS.ProcessedByMetricExtractors": "(Name:'Requests', Ver:'1.1')"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I think that I am not receiving the Json Date from the client correctly. My thinking is  because I am sending the whole model back, which is a Json list, which but My controller does not receiver a List rather a string.

Can any one explain how my controller should receive the client side data
Here is my call to my Controller from the client and the server Post controller and  full code listing is below

```
 self.postAllReqs = function(self) {
        self.error(''); // Clear error message
        var data = ko.toJSON(self.Reqs); // convert to json
        console.log(data);
        ajaxHelper(reqsUri, 'POST', data).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            self.error(errorThrown);
        });
    }

  // POST: api/ReqsTests
    public IHttpActionResult PostReqsTest(string json)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }


        XmlDocument doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);

        try
        {
            //SQL store procedure

            SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@XmlIn", doc);

            db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec [CHC_Web].[TestWebHandShake],@XmlIn",
                                          param1);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string message = e.Message;
              return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, message));                 
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

Thanks

View Model Code

```
    function ReqsTest(rt) {
    rt = rt || {};
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(rt.ID || 0);
    self.requisition = ko.observable(rt.Requisition || "");
    self.reqnStatus = ko.observable(rt.ReqnStatus || "");
    self.dateReqnRaised = ko.observable(rt.DateReqnRaised|| null);
    self.reqnValue = ko.observable(rt.ReqnValue || null);
    self.approvedValue = ko.observable(rt.ApprovedValue || null);
    self.originator = ko.observable(rt.Originator || "");
    self.origName = ko.observable(rt.OrigName || "");
    self.origEmail = ko.observable(rt.OrigEmail || "");
    self.line = ko.observable(rt.Line || 0.00);
    self.indx = ko.observable(rt.INDX || 0);
    self.dateReqnRaisedL = ko.observable(rt.DateReqnRaisedL || null);
    self.reqStatus = ko.observable(rt.ReqStatus || "");
    //self.reqBackground = ko.observable(rt.ReqBackground || "");


    //Computed observables
    self.reqBackground = ko.computed(function () {
        // get variable 
        var status = self.reqStatus();
        if (status == "A") { return "card-heading bg-success text-white"; }
        else if (status == "D") { return "card heading bg-secondary"; }
        else if (status == "R") { return "card heading bg-warning"; }
        else if (status == "E") { return "card heading bg-danger"; }
        else {
            return "card-heading bg-primary text-white";
        }
    })
    self.reqStatusLabel = ko.computed(function () {
        // get variable 
        var status = self.reqStatus();
        if (status == "A") { return "Approved"; }
        else if (status == "D") { return "Declined - put on hold"; }
        else if (status == "R") { return "Routing On"; }
        else if (status == "E") { return "Erase On Syspro"; }
        else {
            return "Awaiting Approval";
        }
    })

    self.approvalBtn = ko.computed(function () {
        // get variable 
        var status = self.reqStatus();
        if (status == "A") { return "css: button btn-secondary "; }
        else {
            return "btn btn-success ";
        }
    })

    self.approvalBtnLbl = ko.computed(function () {
        // get variable 
        var status = self.reqStatus();
        if (status == "W") { return "Approve"; }
        else {
            return "UnApprove";
        }
    })



    self.declineBtnLbl = ko.computed(function () {
        // get variable 
        var status = self.reqStatus();
        if (status == "D") { return "UnDecline"; }
        else {
            return "Decline";
        }
    })

    self.deleteBtnLbl = ko.computed(function () {
        // get variable 
        var status = self.reqStatus();
        if (status == "E") { return "Restore"; }
        else {
            return "Erase";
        }
    })

    // Functions
    //show details alert
    $(".btn").on("click", function () {
        $(".alert").removeClass("in").show();
        $(".alert").delay(200).addClass("in").fadeOut(2000);
    });

}


function ReqsViewModel (){
    var self = this;
    self.Reqs = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.error = ko.observable();

    var reqsUri = '/api/ReqsTests/';

    function ajaxHelper(uri, method, data) {
        self.error(''); // Clear error message
        return $.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: uri,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            self.error(errorThrown);
        });
    }

    function getAllReqs() {
        ajaxHelper(reqsUri, 'GET').done(function (data) {
            // Build the ReqsTest objects
            var reqs = ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function (rt) {
                return new ReqsTest(rt);
            });
            self.Reqs(reqs);
        });

    }

self.postAllReqs = function(self) {
        self.error(''); // Clear error message
        var data = ko.toJSON(self.Reqs); // convert to json
        console.log(data);
        ajaxHelper(reqsUri, 'POST', data).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            self.error(errorThrown);
        });
    }



     // Details
    self.detail = ko.observable();

    self.getReqDetail = function (item) {

        //var url = reqsUri + item.indx();

        //ajaxHelper(url, 'GET').done(function (data) {
        //    self.detail(data);
        //}

        //);
        self.detail(item)
    }

    //Approval function
    self.Approval = function (item) {

        var status = item.reqStatus();

        if (status == "W") { item.reqStatus("A"); }
        else
        { item.reqStatus("W"); }
        self.getReqDetail(item);

    }

    //Decline function
    self.Decline = function (item) {

        var status = item.reqStatus();

        if (status == "D") { item.reqStatus("W"); }
        else { item.reqStatus("D"); }

        self.getReqDetail(item);


    }

    //Delete function
    self.Delete = function (item) {

        var status = item.reqStatus();

        if (status == "E") { item.reqStatus("W"); }
        else { item.reqStatus("E"); }
        self.getReqDetail(item);


    }


    // Load the reqs - Take this out if you don't want it
    getAllReqs();
}




ko.applyBindings(new ReqsViewModel());
```

Model Class

```
 namespace POC_Reqs_v1.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class ReqsTest
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Requisition { get; set; }
        public string ReqnStatus { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateReqnRaised { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> ReqnValue { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> ApprovedValue { get; set; }
        public string Originator { get; set; }
        public string OrigName { get; set; }
        public string OrigEmail { get; set; }
        public decimal Line { get; set; }
        public long INDX { get; set; }
        public string DateReqnRaisedL { get; set; }
        public string ReqStatus { get; set; }
        public string ReqBackground { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller Code

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using System.Xml;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using POC_Reqs_v1.Models;

namespace POC_Reqs_v1.Controllers
{
    public class ReqsTestsController : ApiController
    {
        private ChamberlinWebEntities db = new ChamberlinWebEntities();

        // GET: api/ReqsTests
        public IQueryable<ReqsTest> GetReqsTests()
        {
            return db.ReqsTests;
        }

        // GET: api/ReqsTests/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(ReqsTest))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetReqsTest(string id)

        {
            var ID = Convert.ToInt64(id);
            ReqsTest reqsTest = await db.ReqsTests.FindAsync(ID);
            if (reqsTest == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(reqsTest);
        }

        // PUT: api/ReqsTests/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutReqsTest(string id, ReqsTest reqsTest)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != reqsTest.ID)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.Entry(reqsTest).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!ReqsTestExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }

        // POST: api/ReqsTests
    public IHttpActionResult PostReqsTest(string json)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }


        XmlDocument doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);

        try
        {
            //SQL store procedure

            SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@XmlIn", doc);

            db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec [CHC_Web].[TestWebHandShake],@XmlIn",
                                          param1);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string message = e.Message;
              return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, message));                 
        }

        return Ok();
    }

        // DELETE: api/ReqsTests/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(ReqsTest))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteReqsTest(string id)
        {
            ReqsTest reqsTest = await db.ReqsTests.FindAsync(id);
            if (reqsTest == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            db.ReqsTests.Remove(reqsTest);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Ok(reqsTest);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private bool ReqsTestExists(string id)
        {
            return db.ReqsTests.Count(e => e.ID == id) > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The controller code should just be return status that is completed the task.  Not the XML data.  The XML data should go directly into the database.

Comment: Hi can give me an example of the return status syntax pls

Comment: See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758615/why-should-i-use-ihttpactionresult-instead-of-httpresponsemessage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For completeness here was my final solution:
The main problem was the syntax error in the post controller, which did not create an error when compiled, the line that was incorrect was

```
// POST: api/ReqsTests
public IHttpActionResult PostReqsTest(string json)
```

The correct syntax was in the end

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostReqsTest(object json)
```

So the full controller code is was

```
// POST: api/ReqsTests
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostReqsTest(object json)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        //convert the Json model to xml
        XmlDocument doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json.ToString());

        try
        {
            //SQL store procedure
            SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@XmlIn", doc.InnerXml);
           db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec [CHC_Web].[TestWebHandShake] @XmlIn",
                                          param1);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string message = e.Message;
            return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, message));
        }

       return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse HttpStatusCode.OK,"Inserted to database"));        }
```

Comment: I suppse the last line of code should not be CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK) since it's not an error?