# Web api 2 with a data access layer called by the web api controller method. Getting casting error

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm getting:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage' to type 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult

Web api2 controller method calls a data access layer that returns an int. It fails on the cast:

```
return (IHttpActionResult)httpResponse;
```

Code:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("registeruser/{currentDateTime}/{userName}/{userPassword}/{ipAddress}/")]
public IHttpActionResult RegisterUser(DateTime currentDateTime, string userName, string userPassword, string ipAddress)
{
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponse;

            int returnValue = 0;

            returnValue = dataaccesslayer.RegisterUser(currentDateTime, userName, userPassword, ipAddress);

            httpResponse = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, returnValue);

            return (IHttpActionResult)httpResponse;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
}
```

Data access layer called by web api2 controller method - it returns an int:

```
public int RegisterUser(DateTime currentDateTime, string userName, string userPassword, string ipAddress)
{
        int returnedValue = 0;

        try
        {
            dbFunc.OpenDB();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.RegisterUser", dbFunc.objConn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a_CurrentDateTime", currentDateTime);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a_UserName", userName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a_UserPassword", userPassword);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a_IpAddress", ipAddress);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@a_UserIdOut", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters["@a_UserIdOut"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            returnedValue = (int)cmd.Parameters["@a_UserIdOut"].Value;

            return returnedValue;
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlex)
        {
            throw sqlex;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Close the database.
            dbFunc.CloseDB();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the `IHttpActionResult` try this:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("registeruser/{currentDateTime}/{userName}/{userPassword}/{ipAddress}/")]
public IHttpActionResult RegisterUser(DateTime currentDateTime, string userName, string userPassword, string ipAddress)
{
    try
    {
        IHttpActionResult response;
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponse;

        int returnValue = 0;

        returnValue = dataaccesslayer.RegisterUser(currentDateTime, userName, userPassword, ipAddress);

        httpResponse = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, returnValue);

        response = ResponseMessage(httpResponse);
        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

If it is no problem for you to remove it, then do it like this:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("registeruser/{currentDateTime}/{userName}/{userPassword}/{ipAddress}/")]
public HttpResponseMessage RegisterUser(DateTime currentDateTime, string userName, string userPassword, string ipAddress)
{
    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponse;

        int returnValue = 0;

        returnValue = dataaccesslayer.RegisterUser(currentDateTime, userName, userPassword, ipAddress);

        httpResponse = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, returnValue);

        return httpResponse;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

For a longer discussion on between the two, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758615/why-should-i-use-ihttpactionresult-instead-of-httpresponsemessage) here.

Comment: Where is responseMsg defined and set?

Comment: I wan to keep the IHttpActionResult. But the 'responseMsg' is not recognized.

Comment: Glad to help :)