# Azure Functions - Difference between return type HttpResponseMessage and IActionResult

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have created Http Trigger Azure Function and its default return type is `Task<IActionResult>`.

Is there any difference if I changed it to `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`?

Azure function with `Task<IActionResult>` return type:

```
 public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
```

Azure function with `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`

```
 public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)]
            HttpRequestMessage message,
```

Comment: Check out this link, hope it helps with your request.
[Why should I use IHttpActionResult instead of HttpResponseMessage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758615/why-should-i-use-ihttpactionresult-instead-of-httpresponsemessage#23204155)

Answer (score 7):

> Is there any difference if I changed `Task<IActionResult>` to `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`?

You can use the `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` to be the return type of your function. There shouldn't be a problem in executing with that.

Having said that, the difference between using the two lies in just the way you return response from your function.

- In case of an `IActionResult` type of response, there is lesser code
  to write while constructing a response and it makes unit testing
  simpler.
- On the other hand, `HttpResponseMessage` gives more control on the
  Http response message sent across the wire.

Just as a side note,

In `HttpTrigger` Azure function `v1.0`, types `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` and `HttpRequestMessage` were used as defaults for return type and request type respectively.

From `v2.0` onwards, types `Task<IActionResult>` and `HttpRequest` are being used as default return type and request type respectively as it conforms to .net core API structure.